# How to write Case Sensitive Query for MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, case-sensitive

I want to know the Select Query for MS Access with case sensitive.

I have two values for VitualMonitorName as below

```
VCode VirtualMonitorName
Row 1 (1, 'VM1');
Row 2 (2, 'Vm1');
```

Here both values are different.

If I write

```
"SELECT VCode FROM VirtualMaster WHERE VirtualMonitorName like '" + Vm1 + "'";
```

It replies VCode = 1 Only.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `StrComp()` function with `vbBinaryCompare` for a case-sensitive comparison.  Here is an example from the Immediate window to show how `StrComp()` works.  See the Access help topic for more details.

```vbs
? StrComp("a", "A", vbBinaryCompare)
 1 

? StrComp("a", "A",vbTextCompare)
0
```

`StrComp()` returns 0 if the first two arguments evaluate as equal, 1 or -1 if they are unequal, and Null if either argument is Null.

To use the function in a query, supply the `vbBinaryCompare` constant's value (0) rather than its name.

```sql
SELECT VCode
FROM VirtualMaster
WHERE StrComp(VirtualMonitorName, "Vm1", 0) = 0;
```

This approach is also available to queries from other applications if they use the newer Access Database Engine ("ACE") drivers. For example, the following C# code

```csharp
string myConnectionString =
        @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
        @"Dbq=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = 
                "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM [VirtualMaster] " +
                "WHERE StrComp([VirtualMonitorName],?,?) = 0";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "Vm1");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.Int);

        var vbCompareOptions = new Dictionary<string, int>() 
        {
            {"vbBinaryCompare", 0},
            {"vbTextCompare", 1}
        };
        string currentOption = "";

        currentOption = "vbBinaryCompare";
        cmd.Parameters[1].Value = vbCompareOptions[currentOption];
        Console.WriteLine(
                "{0} found {1} record(s)", 
                currentOption, 
                Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));

        currentOption = "vbTextCompare";
        cmd.Parameters[1].Value = vbCompareOptions[currentOption];
        Console.WriteLine(
                "{0} found {1} record(s)",
                currentOption,
                Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));
    }
}
```

produces

```
vbBinaryCompare found 1 record(s)
vbTextCompare found 2 record(s)
```

Comment: Note: if you are using this in a query (as opposed to a vb script), you have to use the numeric value as the vb constants will throw an error

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/244693?wa=wsignin1.0

This article describes four methods of achieving a case-sensitive JOIN using the Microsoft Jet database engine. Each of these methods has advantages and disadvantages that should be weighed before choosing an implementation. The methods are:

- StrComp
- Case-Sensitive IISAM Driver
- Hexadecimal Expansion
- Binary Field

Answer (score 1):

Using only built-in functions, add an additional custom column in the query design view:

```
location: InStr(1,[VCode],"VM1",0)
```

the zero parameter requests binary compare (case sensitive) when finding location of "VM1" within `[VCode]`

set the criteria in that column to `>0` so only records with non-zero location in the vcode matching `Like "*vm*"` contain the exact VM1 string -

The `WHERE` clause looks like:

```
WHERE (((VirtualMaster.VCode) Like "\*vm*") AND ((InStr(1,[VCode],"VM1",0))>0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using at a simpler level of coding.

As a condition in a DCOUNT operation, checking on a Field (Column)  that has to have the correct Case, and ignoring Blank States/Territories.

```
      '  lngcounter will count the all States 
      ' or Territories Field ( Column) with this 
      ' exact case value of 'Ohio'. ([ID] is an Autonumber ID field)

      lngCounter = DCount("[id]", Trim(Me!tboDwellingTablename), "[State/territory],'Ohio',0) = 0")
```

Comment: hello it might help if your code used the questions example code. It may make it easier for the asker to apply your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This only does one letter:

MS-ACCESS SQL:

```
SELECT Asc(Left([Title],1)) AS t FROM Master WHERE (((Asc(Left([Title],1)))=105));
```

`Title` is the field you want to search

`Master` is the Table where `Title` field is located

`105` Ascii code for character..

In this case only Title's that start with i not I

If you want to search for lower case "a" you would change the 105 to 97