# How to perform case sensitive group by in MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, group-by, union-all, ms-access-2016

In MS Access database to find the mismatch (i.e. difference) records between two tables(Employee and Employee_PROD) I am using the **UNION ALL**. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT [COMPANY],[DEPT],[DOJ],[EMP_ID],[Name],[SUB_COMPANY] FROM 

(SELECT '[Employee]' AS TableName,[COMPANY],[DEPT],[DOJ],[EMP_ID],[Name],[SUB_COMPANY] FROM [Employee] 

UNION ALL 

SELECT '[Employee_PROD]' AS TableName,[COMPANY],[DEPT],[DOJ],[EMP_ID],[Name],[SUB_COMPANY] FROM [Employee_PROD] ) 

GROUP BY [COMPANY],[DEPT],[DOJ],[EMP_ID],[Name],[SUB_COMPANY] 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MIN(TableName) = '[Employee]'
```

The problem I am facing is that the `GROUP BY` is not considering the case sensitivity. For example "**a**ndrew" and "**A**ndrew" is treated as same. I want to perform group by with case sensitive to find the difference records.

Is there any way to do the same in MS Access?

Is there any other approach to find the differences between two tables having same column names, data types and the number of records is 7,00, 000?

I have tried the following:

- Load data to `DataTable` and then find the difference. Got out of memory exception due to huge amount of data.
- Use `NOT EXISTS` to compare the rows. The query got hanged and the execution never completed.
- The `UNION ALL` approach is working but the issue is that `GROUP BY` is not considering the case sensitivity.

Comment: C# or Access ??

Comment: I am executing the query in MS Access database via C# OleDbConnection.

Comment: If so, I'm not sure, you can call VBA functions in Access. But you could pick the ASCII value of the first character, if that is what you care about. For more subsequent characters you might expand that using MID.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by the byte value:

```
? StrToByte("Andrew")
416E64726577
? StrToByte("andrew")
616E64726577
```

though it might be a bit slow with the large amount of data you have.

```
Public Function StrToByte(ByVal strChars As String) As String

  Dim abytChar()  As Byte
  Dim lngChar     As Long
  Dim strByte     As String

  abytChar() = StrConv(strChars, vbFromUnicode)

  strByte = Space(2 * (1 + UBound(abytChar) - LBound(abytChar)))
  For lngChar = LBound(abytChar) To UBound(abytChar)
    Mid(strByte, 1 + 2 * lngChar) = Hex(abytChar(lngChar))
  Next

  StrToByte = strByte

End Function
```

For SQL only, and if you only about the first character, try:

```
GROUP BY [COMPANY],[DEPT],[DOJ],[EMP_ID],[Name], ASC([Name]),[SUB_COMPANY]
```

Comment: Since it's from C# (assumption since the question is tagged C#), you probably can't use UDFs

Comment: I noticed, but: _Is there any way to do the same in MS Access?_ So?

Comment: As said, it's an assumption. If it's actually just access, the C# tag should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not specify OPTION COMPARE BINARY in a module to perform a case sensitive search?

This thread https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=33962 and this one [How to write Case Sensitive Query for MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046627/how-to-write-case-sensitive-query-for-ms-access) both describe different methods.

Comment: I don't want to perform the search action but the group by query.

Comment: Apologies I missed that subtle difference in the question - this might assist https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/244693/how-to-perform-a-case-sensitive-join-through-microsoft-jet