# Case Sensitive Login using SQL, VB.NET, and Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have created a login which connects to an Access Database. It works fine except the password input is case insensitive. I have tested this using passwords such as one ONE and One, all of which result in a successful login. How do I change the SQL query to stop this happening?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'd like to point out that this is not a good way to authenticate.  You shouldn't store the password in plain text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [username and password verification vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713267/username-and-password-verification-vb-net) (which includes information on how to do passwords properly).

Answer (score 2):

You must use *StrComp(string1, string2, compare)* with `binary` comparison. Returns 0 when strings are equal

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM [tblCustomer] WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID and StrComp(Password, @Password, 0) = 0
```

See [Doc](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_strcomp.asp)