# Perform a case-sensitive sql query with StrComp funtion for MS Access in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, case-sensitive

I am new to C#. I tried to write a case-sensitive sql query for Microsoft Access in C#.
Here is part of the table named "EmployeeList". Notice the second record has a lower case for "s":

```
| ID   | Name      | InternalID |
|:----:|:---------:| :---------:|
| 8    | John Smith| 52455      |
| 9    | John smith| 49         |
| ...  | ...       | ...        |
```

Here is the query. I tested in Access, and it worked well.

```
SELECT InternalID FROM EmployeeList WHERE StrComp(Name, 'John Smith', 0) = 0;
```

What is the correct syntax to write it in C#? I have looked up many sources but my code is still wrong:

```
public DataTable findInternalID(string name)
        {
            Connection.Open();
            DataTable output = new DataTable();
            OleDbCommand bdCommand = RecordConnection.CreateCommand() as OleDbCommand;
            
            StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
            x.AppendLine("SELECT InternalID ");
            x.AppendLine("FROM EmployeeList ");
            x.AppendLine($"WHERE StrComp(Name, @name, 0) = 0");
          
            bdCommand.CommandText = x.ToString();
            bdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", $"%{name}%");

            _dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(bdCommand);
            _dataAdapter.Fill(output);

            RecordConnection.Close();
            return output;

        }
```

and here is the code under main to test my function:

```
string name = "John Smith";
DataTable output = _accessManager.findInternalID(name);
String message;
message = output.Rows[0][0].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

and this code throws me an error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 0.'

Why there's no record written into result?

Comment: Don't use string comparison in the where statement. Just send WHERE Name = @name

Comment: @GHDevOps Hi, thanks for the feedback. Since sql query in MS Access is case insensitive, if I simply use NAME=@name, then it will recognize "John Smith" and  "John smith" as the same thing

Answer (score 0):

`StrComp` is an Access function, not a SQL Server function.

So this will get rid of the error:

`commandTextBuilder.AppendLine($"WHERE Name = @name");`

However, that's not case-sensitive.

You can use `StrComp` if you use newer drivers, as per here:

[How to write Case Sensitive Query for MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046627/how-to-write-case-sensitive-query-for-ms-access)

If this were SQL Server, you'd want to change the column to be case-sensitive. The command to do so looks something like

```
ALTER TABLE <mytable>
ALTER COLUMN <mycolumn> VARCHAR(<mylength>) 
COLLATE <myencoding>
```

Just fill in the blanks. `myencoding` will be whatever the current encoding is, with *CI* replaced with *CS*. If you're running defaults, that means going from `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, this ALTER TABLE feature can't be used for MS Access.

Comment: Amended answer. This question might actually be a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually figured out how to use `StrComp` in my function, simply change ```bdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", $"%{name}%");``` to ```bdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", $"{name}");```. Lol, so the `%` is actually the problem when I tried to do parameterized sql query.